# Passing file parameter directly to FileReader

Tags: javascript, html, text-files, filereader

I'm trying to make a webpage for school closings, so I have to write to a file using javascript. I've been looking at the FileReader but I couldnt find a way to pass a link to the file instead of using a variable from an input or anything. I'm a noob within the javascript world so i can't describe to you much but here's the code:

```
<head>
        <title>
            Ohio School Closings Home
        </title>
        <style>
            body{
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <script>

            var reader = new FileReader();
            var closingsFile = reader.readAsText('closings.txt');
            document.getElementById("textContents").innerHTML = closingFile;

            function test(){
                alert("javascipt is working");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Ohio School Closings</h1>
        <h4><a href="search.html">Search</a>-<a href="apps.html">App</a>-<a href="admincontrol.html">Admin Control Panel</a></h4>
        <br>
        <h2>Current Closings</h2>
        <p id="textContents">There are currently no closings</p>
        <h2><a href="http:\\www.facebook.com\ohioschoolclosings">Facebook</a></h2>
        <button onClick="test()">Test Javascript<!--Checks for syntax errors temporarilly, will be removed--></button>
```

Comment: The HTML code isn't fully finished yet :)

Comment: use this `instanceOfFileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);`

Comment: One problem i'm having is how do i define 'blob'

Comment: You don't define Blob, either your browser (javascript engine knows about it) or you can't use it. Chrome, Safari, Opera, FireFox and IE > 10 can all use Blob . If you're using another browser (IE9 or less then you can't) take a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader and http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls

Comment: Also if you actually want to write contents to a file then its much harder. Instead take a look at using something like filesaver http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: You cannot just read a file on the users computer, the user will have to select it from a file input.

Comment: Im trying to access a file on the server side

Comment: Then look into Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use PHP to read and write the files on the server.



Replace $filename with file path

```
//READ FILE
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$filecontents = fread($file, filesize($filename));

echo nl2br($filecontents); //if you want to display the text as it would appear in the file
```